# Xpages link to open document view

Tags: view, xpages, xpages-ssjs

I want to add an option to the row of the view: the possibility to open the document when clicking on the row. It is possible? How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add `displayAs="link"` to viewColumn. Then it is rendered as link and opens the document if you click on it. You can also choose to open it in edit or read mode.

Set the attributes in properties panel:

[image]

**Update:**

You can open the corresponding document clicking somewhere on a **viewPanel's row** (not just on a column's link) if you add a `rowAttrs` property.

Add the following code to your viewPanel:

```xml
<xp:viewPanel
    rows="30"
    id="viewPanel1"
    var="row">
    ...
    <xp:this.rowAttrs>
        <xp:attr
            value="window.open('#{javascript:row.getOpenPageURL(null, true)}', '_self')"
            name="onclick"
            rendered="#{javascript:!(row.isCategory() | row.isTotal())  }">
        </xp:attr>
    </xp:this.rowAttrs>
</xp:viewPanel>
```

Set viewPanel's row variable to `var="row"`. The attribute `attr` gets rendered for all rows which are represent a document. It adds an individual `onclick` event to those rows and executes CSJS code defined in `value`. This CSJS code contains a SSJS part which inserts the URL of the document as window.open's parameter.

If you set getOpenPageURL's second parameter to `false` then document will be opened in edit mode.

Look [here](http://planetlotus.org/profiles/innerringsolutions_111201) for a detailed description.

Comment: I know this, but I want to add this property to the whole row, not to the text inside the columns.

Comment: the rowAttr is not by default available by the view panel control, but for the data table control?

Comment: @Patrick: rowAttr is available at "All Properties / basics" for both view panel and data table control.

Answer (score -1):

I think there is no easy way ;-) Maybe JQuery is your friend to add a on click event to the row with needed